# React Typescript stateless component, SFC vs StatelessComponent

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I can use either of the following to create react stateless component using typescript.
But what is the difference between these two?

```
type SFC<P = {}> = FunctionComponent<P>;

type StatelessComponent<P = {}> = FunctionComponent<P>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Digging into the types definitions file for React, we can see SFC is simply an equivalent type for a StatelessComponent.

Its personal preference which syntax you prefer.

**@types/react/index.d.ts**

```
type SFC<P = {}> = StatelessComponent<P>;
```